# Django form not saving to database

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble saving form fields to my database. I know that it isn't saving because if I look at the Player model in django, there is always 0 data. If anyone could take a look and correct me, I would be very thankful.

models.py -

```
from django.db import models

class Player(models.Model):
    player_one_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    player_two_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
```

forms.py -

```
from django import forms

class PlayerInfo(forms.Form):
    player_one_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='First player name')
    player_two_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Second player name')
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
import os
from .forms import PlayerInfo
from .models import Player

def start(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PlayerInfo(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = Player()
            obj.player_one_name = form.cleaned_data['player_one_name']
            obj.player_two_name = form.cleaned_data['player_two_name']
            return HttpResponseRedirect('game/')

    else:
        form = PlayerInfo()

        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'start.html', args)
```

start.html - Meant to submit each player's name

```
{% block botRow %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

game.html - Meant to render each player's name

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block midRow %}
    <p>{{ fpn }}</p>
    <p>{{ spn }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation!

Comment: You probably want to use a `ModelForm`.

Comment: The code has been updated to fix a couple errors. But it is still not being saved to the database.

Comment: The code in *forms.py* and *views.py* is not correctly indented.

Answer (score 1):

The request method is always in all caps.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Comment: Hi, should it be lower case? I had put it in all caps because the tutorial that I was following wrote it in caps.

Comment: No it should be all caps as I have shown it, not mixed case as you have.

Comment: Okay, I've fixed this issue. However, it still does not get posted to the databse.